# Is this a real photo of NYC?

Tags: aerial-photography, forensics

I found this somewhere online, unattributed.  I'm wondering if it's synthetic or a real photo.  If it's real, how has it been shot and/or post-processed to make it look so much like a computer game - or is that just what Central Park looks like?

[image]

Comment: Thats insane! it looks like Sim City!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE. Unfortunately I have downvoted this question as this shows little research effort. [Google Image Search](https://www.google.nl/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ei=EaHIUuCIMYOK0AXI7oEI&ved=0CAQQqi4oAg) can easily be used to find the author + background info of this image.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good point, especially given that you can [drag and drop images](http://bit.ly/1dFucYg) into Google Image Search these days. Vague apologies for the use of the URL shortener, but it was much too long for a comment otherwise...

Comment: A downvote is a bit harsh considering someone might never have heard that you can now search the internet by image. I know many people who are unaware you can do this.

Answer (score 7):

A quick Google found me [this page](http://insidersvacationguide.com/central-park-new-york-city-from-above/), where it says: "Russian photographer Sergey Semenov shows you the NYC Central Park the way you’ve never seen it before. The amazing picture that won Semenov the best amateur award from the International Pano Awards, is stitched together from a bunch of 360-degree panoramic pictures, taken from a helicopter."

Once you've got the Semenov name, you can find more pages about this than you'll probably ever have time to read for instance [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/01/12/sergey-semonovs-aerial-panorama-new-york-city-pano-awards_n_2463171.html) and an interactive version of the panorama at the [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2260276/New-York-youve-seen-Incredible-interactive-panorama-lets-zoom.html).